# HTML5 geolocaton result moves off my webpage - how to stop that?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get more familiar with HTML5.  I am an experienced programmer, but a javascript neophyte. I've written some code to getCurrentPosition (which results in an async callback when the position is fixed).  Here's the code (I already tested for, and got a positive response on, support for geolocation on this platform):

```
 function tryGeo() {
     document.write("asking for location <br>");
     try {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(savePos);
   } catch (e) {
     document.write("Excpn in asking for location <br>");
   }
     document.write("have asked for location <br>");
}
```

When that code runs, it pops up the permission request window or dialog.  I grant permission.  This is on Firefox 3.6.8 on MacOS 10.6.7.

Some time later, the callback to savePos() happens (when the position is known):

```
function savePos(pos) {
   lat = pos.coords.latitude;
   lon = pos.coords.longitude;
   document.write("have got location lat " +lat+ ", lon " +lon+ " <br>");
}
```

***The problem I'm having is that that document.write() moves to a new blank page.  Instead, I want to add the text to the page I was rendering when I make the getCurrentPosition() request.   How can I do that?***

I'm probably making some trivial beginner's error - please let me know what.

Also, links to "learn javascript for Experienced Coders" resources would be appreciated.  Thaks,

Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just how [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/document.write) works:

> Writing to a document that has already loaded without calling `document.open()` will automatically perform a `document.open` call.

And [`document.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.open):

> If a document exists in the target, this method clears it.

And their example just above that note:

```
// In this example, the document contents are 
// overwritten as the document 
// is reinitialized on open(). 
document.write("<html><p>remove me</p></html>"); 
document.open(); 
// document is empty.
```

The easiest thing to do is to have an element already on the page and then update that element's content. So, you'd have a bit of HTML:

```
<p id="you-are-here"></p>
```

And then in the callback:

```
document.getElementById('you-are-here').innerHTML = "have got location lat " + lat + ", lon " + lon;
```

So, yeah, your trivial beginner's error is using `document.write` on a document that has already loaded.